# nslookup and dig error: connection timed out; no servers could be reached - even when specifying server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, nslookup, dig

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and my internet suddenly stopped working.

I can ping local and WAN ip addresses and I have already restarted the network:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

These commands:

```
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1
dig google.com @1.1.1.1
```

both return: `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

But dig in tcp mode works perfectly:

```
dig google.com @1.1.1.1 +tcp
```

`ifconfig` looks the usual.

I'm clueless as to what is happening. I don't know what's the service that's causing this that needs to restart. I know for a fact that rebooting fixes this problem since this has happened to me before so I thought I could ask this question to help for the future, so I understand what's going on.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo iptables-save; sudo ip6tables-save; sudo nft list ruleset`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be not actual anymore but I had very same issue and figured out the reason. The resolver was `systemd-resolved` and listened on 127.0.0.53. **But** my `iptables` has `DROP` policy on `INPUT` table and no rule allowing access to `lo` interface. I added this rule and it started coming!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with iptables and selinux; you must check all network services status once on your machine.

The issue I found is network.service ; was failing on the vm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).